# Inverse of a function with summation

Tags: inverse-function

Suppose that I have the following function:
$$z(\zeta)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}m_k\zeta^{1-k}$$

How do I get the inverse of that function? i.e. I want to express $\zeta(z)$?

In my case, $10\leq n \leq 20$.

In my case, $z$ cannot be zero and the constants $m_k$ is not arbitrary but rather obtained from another process. This is actually a conformal mapping function that can map any shape into a unit circle, thus $z$ cannot be zero.

Is it possible to have a general rule to defined $\zeta(z)$? I can then translate them into Matlab, for instance.

Comment: nobody is interested to reply to my question? :)

Answer (score 0):

In general your function will not have an inverse function.

Consider for example
$$z(\zeta):=\zeta-3+\frac{2}{\zeta}$$
which has the property
$$z(1)=z(2)=0.$$
Thus, it's not one-to-one and you can't define an inverse function on the whole range of $z$.

Comment: In my case, $z$ cannot be zero and the constants $m_k$ is not arbitrary but rather obtained from another process. This is actually a conformal mapping function that can map any shape into a unit circle, thus $z$ cannot be zero.

Comment: Then you should add these additional condition to your question!

Comment: Done. I have added the condition into my question. ^_^